# Glide won't show my images from Firebase when ran via physical device

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database, android-glide

I'm having these warnings when trying to launch my app using my phone (Samsung) and won't display any of the images.

```
W/Glide: Load failed for https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/inventory-app-75a9a.appspot.com/o/Alice5.jpg?alt=media&token=e290979d-cfdf-451c-9103-2e003f446009 with size [255x298]
class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Failed to load resource
There was 1 root cause:
com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
  Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetching data failed, class java.io.InputStream, REMOTE
There was 1 root cause:
com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
    Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.engine.GlideException: Fetch failed
There was 1 root cause:
com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException(Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1)
 call GlideException#logRootCauses(String) for more detail
      Cause (1 of 1): class com.bumptech.glide.load.HttpException: Failed to connect or obtain data, status code: -1
```

But when I launch my app via the emulator it works perfectly fine.

```
if (products.get(position).getImageUrl() != null){
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(products.get(position).getImageUrl())
                .into(holder.productImg);
    } else {
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(R.drawable.applogo)
                .into(holder.productImg);
    }
```

I tried replacing the URL link from some random picture on the internet and it displays the image on my phone.

```
if (products.get(position).getImageUrl() != null){
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load("https://www.borsheims.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2020/06/types-of-earrings.jpg")
                .into(holder.productImg);
    } else {
        Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(R.drawable.applogo)
                .into(holder.productImg);
    }
```

I also tried updating the link that was stored in my database and it also works fine. The only problem is when the link is from the Firebase Storage

Does anyone know how to fix this and why do the images not load if ran via a physical device?